# android - how to build using Android.bp file (Soong build system)

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

I'm building a native library for Android and its build configuration is `Android.bp`.

How do I execute the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the module you want to build is part of AOSP, you can build it using `mm` command no matter the configuration file is written in bp or mk.